# Super Meat Boy warp zone not completed?

Tags: super-meat-boy

In Super Meat boy I have completed the 1st world and am currently on the second world. I usually like doing everything I can before moving on to a new thing in video games. So I collected all the bangages and got A+ on all the light world levels. But I noticed when I completed *Sky Pup* and *Hand Held Mask* they still were purple. But when I completed The *Commander!* it turned red. I've collected the two bandages on each and completed them. Is there a way to turn them red/complete them or do they just stay like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not supposed to.

According to [Super Meat Boy Wiki](http://supermeatboy.wikia.com/wiki/Warp_Zone):

> **Bandage Warp Zone** appears three times per world. (2 in light world, 1 in dark world).
>   When viewing them from the map, they are *purple* in the light world, and *black* vice-versa.
>
> **Character Warp Zone** appears once per world.
>   When being viewed from the map, or when entering one, they are *red*.